# Create customer programatically using setData

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, collection

i have a dynamic data array which contain customer data, the data inside the array will be variative, thats why i'm using setData function to insert the customer data to customer model like this:

```
 $data0['website_id'] = '0';
 $data0['group_id'] = '1';
 $data0['firstname'] = 'Bruce';
 $data0['lastname'] = 'Wayne';
 $data0['email'] = 'batman@cave.com';
 $data0['password'] = 'BecauseIAmBatman';
 $data1['website_id'] = '0';
 $data1['group_id'] = '1';
 $data1['firstname'] = 'Clark';
 $data1['lastname'] = 'Kent';
 $data1['email'] = 'super@man.com';
 $data1['gender'] = '1';
 $data1['taxvat'] = '12345';
 $data1['password'] = 'SupermanIsDead';
 $data[] = $data0;
 $data[] = $data1;

 foreach ($data as $dat) {
   $dat = array($dat);
   $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
   $customer->setData($dat); 
   $customer->save();
 }
```

if i run the above code, i got an error like this:

> There has been an error processing your request 
>   Customer email is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below code it will work for you

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once ( "app/Mage.php" );
Mage::app();
 $data['website_id'] = '0';
 $data['group_id'] = '1';
 $data['first_name'] = 'Bruce';
 $data['last_name'] = 'Wayne';
 $data['email'] = 'batman1@cave.com';
 $data['password'] = 'BecauseIAmBatman';

 $data1['website_id'] = '0';
 $data1['group_id'] = '1';
 $data1['first_name'] = 'Second';
 $data1['last_name'] = 'User';
 $data1['email'] = 'user@cave.com';
 $data1['password'] = 'BecauseIAmBatman';

$mainData[]=$data;
$mainData[]=$data1;


foreach($mainData as $data)
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
        $customer->setData($key,$value); 
    }
    $customer->save();  
}
echo "done";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using multiple arrays when you are retrieving your data. You can simply merge them and then set data to model.

```
 $data0['website_id'] = '0';
 $data0['group_id'] = '1';
 $data0['firstname'] = 'Bruce';
 $data0['lastname'] = 'Wayne';
 $data0['email'] = 'batman@cave.com';
 $data0['password'] = 'BecauseIAmBatman';
 $data1['website_id'] = '0';
 $data1['group_id'] = '1';
 $data1['firstname'] = 'Clark';
 $data1['lastname'] = 'Kent';
 $data1['email'] = 'super@man.com';
 $data1['gender'] = '1';
 $data1['taxvat'] = '12345';
 $data1['password'] = 'SupermanIsDead';
 $data = array_merge($data0, $data1);
```

Set the data to your model and save

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setData($data);
$customer->save();
```